# Unable to initialize a function that's in a 2nd javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, babeljs

I have 2 javascript files that I'm working with. File1.js is initializing a function that I've set up in file2.js. However, in my console, I get an error saying that function is not defined.

Am I missing something?

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="file1.js"></script>
```

**FILE1.js**

```
if (x = "foo") {
    doThis();
}
```

**FILE2.js**

```
function doThis() {
    alert("HELLO.");
}
```

Comment: file2.js has an anonymous, *unnamed* function.. How could calling `doThis();` possibly call what's in file2.js?

Comment: Sorry, just caught that mistake in my post. I fixed it to include doThis() the way I have it in my project. Even though I've named it - it still not recognizing it.

Comment: in file1.js you are not checking equality for `x`, by the way. I would have expected to see `if (x === "foo")`

Comment: Gotcha, that's true. The above is a simplified version of what I'm working on... I think the fact that I'm trying to animate SVGs in HTML using functions in another file is messing me up... Not 100% sure though.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Are you sure it's on the line `doThis();`? And how does `babeljs` come into play?

Comment: My exact error is "doThis is not defined". And my File1.js is written in JSX with React.

Comment: It's tricky to say, you've already had to ask us to excuse 2 mistakes that were made for the sake of the post. So without seeing the exact code it's hard to determine what exact problem you're having. It's quite possibly an issue with loading time. Maybe file2.js takes longer to download than file1.js, thus file1.js calls quicker. This, for starters, should all be wrapped in a page load event (if appropriate).

Comment: Thanks, may be the case. React may also be messing me up. I will move my functions into file1 for the sake of it working.